# BroadcastReceiver not working for SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'm trying to register a BroadcastReceiver on activity programmatically by using this code

```
br=new BroadcastReceiver() {                        
            private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
            private static final String TAG = "cyb";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.e(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        }
                        if (messages.length > -1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    };      

    IntentFilter inf=new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    inf.setPriority(999);
    registerReceiver(br, inf);
```

Also i added this permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

My app wont getting any notification when new sms received.I'm using Android 4.2 with Hangout and GoSMS

**Update 2:**

After Uninstalling GOSMS it was working.But i want to receive SMS_RECEIVED intent action, even if the user installed GoSMS app or not.Is it possible? Any alternative solution?

Comment: can you post your log-cat error...

Comment: I didn't get any error,My app is not getting SMS_RECEIVED intent action when new sms received.

Comment: Uninstall GoSMS and try again. Or, try it on a device or emulator that does not have GoSMS. Note that you can simulate SMS messages on an emulator using the Emulator Control tab in DDMS.

Comment: After uninstalling GOSMS it was working.But i want to receive intent action even if the user installed GoSMS or not.Any solution to this problem?

Comment: try adding `android:priority="1000"` attribute for receiver in manifest... by default Eclipse will not show this attribute when you press `ctrl+space`..

Comment: Not working.I set `setPriority(1000);` How GoSMS can able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need also to implement MMS receiver + HeadlessSmsSendService +ComposeSmsActivity

see the link for details:
http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html